# Api platform swagger convert in octal

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I use xml for api platform the column fax is like that :

```xml
<property name="fax" required="false" identifier="false" writable="true" readable="true" description="A fax for the company.">
            <attribute name="openapi_context">
                <attribute name="example">0133333333</attribute>
            </attribute>
</property>
```

When I reach swagger this is what I've got :

```json
"fax": "23967451",
```

It's something completly different. I noticed if I delete "0" the number "133333333" is correctly print. So I converted 0133333333 in octal and the result is "23967451", the same as swagger printed.

I don't understand why, because with the others entity which got a fax column the number is printed correctly.

Fax is the entity :

```php
private ?string $fax = null;
```

In doctrine :

```xml
<field name="fax" type="string" column="fax" length="25" nullable="true"/>
```

And I have no validation for this column.

Any idea ?

Comment: How are you converting to swagger?

Comment: There is nothing about it in api_platform configuration